# Qual è il significato di "straniata" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

In un testo su Pasolini ho letto:

> Questo tema ritorna nel primo film dedicato all'antico, *Edipo Re* (1967), dove Pasolini realizza una reinvenzione incredibilmente **straniata** del testo di Sofocle: Edipo viene spostato in un mondo barbarico, primitivo (il Morocco), e Franco Citti – che lo impersona – conduce una recita elementare, infantile, a tratti inconsapevole.

Non capisco qual è il senso di "straniata" in questa frase. Ho letto quello che spiegano alcuni dizionari sul significato di "straniare" (rendere straneo, allontanare, distogliere) e ho visto che il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/straniare/) menziona che "straniato" può significare anche "fuori di sé, quasi impazzito", ma questo non sembra avere senso nella frase sopra citata. Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il senso di "straniata" nel brano precedente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'effetto di straniamento è una delle possibili tecniche utilizzate nel teatro, soprattutto in quello novecentesco (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/effetto-di-straniamento/). Può essere usato anche in letteratura. L'effetto nello spettatore o nel lettore è quello della messa a fuoco di un binocolo. Secondo l'Enciclopedia Treccani:

> Secondo la teoria drammatica elaborata da B. Brecht, l’effetto di ‘distanza’ che l’attore suscita nello spettatore non identificandosi con il personaggio o con l’ambiente, ma rappresentandolo, grazie alla recitazione e, secondariamente, alla musica e alla scenografia, come diverso da sé, fino a farne qualcosa di noto e di estraneo al tempo stesso. Questa concezione, che ha radici nella cultura teatrale di alcuni paesi orientali o di altri secoli, come nel teatro medievale europeo, è legata alle idee di Brecht sulla funzione sociale e civile del teatro, cioè a un’ideologia che vuole rappresentare in chiave marxista la realtà in divenire. Lo scopo dello s. è infatti non solo quello di evitare il coinvolgimento emotivo dello spettatore, ma anche di suscitare un atteggiamento analitico e critico rispetto ai fatti rappresentati.

Comment: Infatti questo non è teatro, ma è cinema.

Comment: Penso che quello che spiega l'Enciclopedia Treccani abbia perfetto senso in questo contesto. Si tratta di un testo scritto dalla Cineteca di Bologna, quindi è normale che usi un vocabolario in certo modo "tecnico". Per avere una risposta più completa però sarebbe una buona idea includere una spiegazione su in che cosa consiste questo "effetto di straniamento".

Comment: @Charo: grazie dell'aggiunta. :) Ho semplificato la frase che introduce la citazione.

Answer (score 3):

***Straniata***  ossia "resa estranea rispetto a". La reinvenzione dell'Edipo Re è talmente diversa (estranea) rispetto l'originale da renderla quasi irriconoscibile. I tempi e i luoghi di narrazione sono diversi rispetto al contesto originale.